# Symfony2 get all selected checkbox

Tags: php, html, symfony, checkbox, twig

I'm working in a `Symfony2` project, and i have an entity called `File`. In a page i have a list of files and i added a `check-box` for each file, and what i want is to have a `submit button` at the end of the files list and  when i click the button i want the files to be deleted. I've already implement the `action` that will delete the files but i don't know how to get the selected files so i can pass them to the `deleteAction($files)`.

here is the code of the twig file:

```
<tr>
<th>File name</th>                      
<th>Commentary</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>Product/ SN</th>
<th>Added at(UTC)</th>
</tr>

{% for file in allFiles %}
   <tr>                         
     <td class="name">
       <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
         <input type="checkbox" name="check_file"> {{ file.filename }}
       </form>                              
     </td>                                     

   <td>{{ file.uploaderComment }}</td>
   <td>{{ _self.bytesToSize(file.filesize) }}</td>


   <td>{{ file.product }}</td>
   <td>{{ file.added |date("Y/m/d H:i:s","UTC") }}</td>

  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

The Symfony choice form type will take care of your needs.

Comment: i'm not gonna use the form builder i my example, i just wanna delete the selected files

Answer (score 0):

You can add the logic in the controller that handles the form submission.

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // perform some action, such as deleting any file with field marked 'delete'
    $data = $form->getData();
    $data->getFiles();
    $deletethese = new ArrayCollection();
    foreach($files as $file){
        if($file->delete() == true){
            $deletethese->add($file);
        }
}

deleteAction($deletethese);

return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
}
```

Refer to the documentation about [form submissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-submitted-data).